# Move to TabBar item with data using button

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

Hello I want to select tabbar item with some data using button on uiviewController ,  i can move to another tabbar using this but in this method i can't move data

```
let second = self.tabBarController?.viewControllers?[2] as? MyAccountViewController
second?.testValue = "Test Value"
self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 2
```

Crash Report

> Could not cast value of type 'UINavigationController' (0x2496e5280) to
>   'xxxxxx.MyAccountViewController' (0x1016cd4c8). 2019-03-09
>   08:07:34.281652+0500 xxxxx[390:17926] Could not cast value of type
>   'UINavigationController' (0x2496e5280) to
>   'xxxxxx.MyAccountViewController' (0x1016cd4c8).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need  verify that it's the vc with

```
let nav = self.tabBarController!.viewControllers![2] as! UINavigationController 
let second = nav.viewControllers!.first as! MyAccountViewController 
second.testValue = "Test Value"
self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 2
```

If the destination vc is not active ( first time opended ) then print the value inside `viewDidLoad` if it's active then print it inside `viewWillAppear` / `viewDidAppear`

Comment: yes i did in viewWillAppear but its not updating value

Comment: used the guard ? as your code may pass without setting the value for a reason like the destination vc class name is not it

Comment: using guard nothing happens not moving , my viewcontroller on index 2 mean third tab is myaccountviewcontroller

Comment: if so then the guard won't return make sure that it's really `MyAccountViewController ` assigned the class in IB ?

Comment: its assigned from storyboard

Comment: Hey Bro It Works Wow, how did u do this ?